Google Admin API stopped returning custom schemas with projection='full'
I have written a script to pull google user data using the python googleapiclient package which needs include a custom schema so I have included projection='full' in the api call.
This was working perfectly one day and then, inexlicably, stopped including the custom schemas in the response without any change to the code. The custom schema objects are completely missing from the response rather than being empty, i.e. the repsonse is the equivalent of setting projection='basic'.
There have been no changes to the permissions of the service account or the delegated user and when I log in to the admin console using the delegated user I can see and edit the custom schema data. I have tried using different deletaged accounts with the same result.
Is there any other reason why the api response would not include the custom schemas?
I am using Python version 3.11.5 and google-api-python-client 2.115.0.
The relevent section of code is below:
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service_account_key = {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "<project_id>",
        "private_key_id": "<project_key_id>",
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----<private_key>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----/n",
        "client_email": "<service_account@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com>",
        "client_id": "<client_id>",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "<client_x509_cert_url>"
    }

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']
delegate = '<user-sa@domain>'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_key, scopes=scopes)
credentials_delegated = credentials.with_subject(delegate)
api_query = 'isSuspended=False'
customer = '<customer>'
max_results = 500
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials_delegated, cache_discovery=False)

try:
    response = service.users().list(customer=customer, query=api_query,
                                    maxResults=max_results, projection='full').execute()
    print(response)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)

EDIT:
I have discovered the cause of the issue. The custom schmea information was only disappearing if I was only returning a subset of the total pages in the response while testing. So in the code snippet above I am only pulling the first page. By lettig the full script run to return all pages the custom schemas are available.
I don't yet fully understand exactly how the paginated response are structured to have this effect but that will have to be a seperate post/question.

The problem here was that I was only returning a subset of the pages in the full API response.
By running the complete script and including all pages the custom schemas were eventually returned.
